# How to make a div visible after email is sent using PHP

Tags: php, forms

I have the following contact form in my index.html file

```
<div class="alert alert-success visible" id="successmsg"><strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been sent to us.</div>

 <form method="post" action="mail.php" class="contact-form">
          <div class="form-group">               
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">                
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">               
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
          </div>              
          <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
          <button type="submit" data-text="SUBMIT" class="button button-default"><span>SUBMIT</span></button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

The id "successmsg" is hidden in the HTML file using a simple display:none; code & I need to make it visible when the email is sent using the following php

```
<?php$name = $_POST['name'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$formcontent=" Name:\r $name \n\n Email:\r $email \n\n Subject:\r $subject \n\n Message:\r $message ";

$recipient = "towersdvd@gmail.com";

$subject = "Website Contact";

$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader);


<style type="text/css">#lol{display:yes;}</style>
exit;}?>
```

This doesn't work at all. Can someone assist me with this? Really appreciate your kind help. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: `#lol { display: yes }` is not valid CSS either; http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp 'yes' is not a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any 'yes' value for the display property. Try changing it to `{display: block;}` or `{display: inline;}` depending.

Check this link for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using/putting the wrong ID

Please change  `<style type="text/css">#lol{display:yes;}</style>`

TO

<`style type="text/css">#successmsg{display:inline;}</style>`

Hope this will help.